# HTML - p tag showing a different color in the iphone

Tags: iphone, html, css

Thank you very much in advance for the help.

I've built a website and now I'm trying to uptimise it for the iPhone.
I have problems with one page in particular: [broken link to external site](http://www.intelligenthygiene.co.uk/contact/).

The contact telephone numbers are white. But in the iPhone they are green. I've included an screen shot. As you can see the numbers are green (#029547).

I tried to create some css only for the iphone, but still they're green.
I'm obviously missing something but I can't see what.

**Information**:

The [broken link to css file](http://www.intelligenthygiene.co.uk/themes/main_theme/css/default.css).

Line 444:  '.style2'

Lines 707 and 708 contains the css only for the iPhone: '.style2' and'.style2 p'

Cheers!

**UPDATE**:

Adrian, thank you very much for point out that the media declarations were wrong.
I fixed it but the problem still persists.

**UPDATE 2**:

Screenshot: [image]

---

**Solved**:

It was the 'a' attribute in the line line 123.
Yes, that's right. The a attribute was overriding the `.style2` p attribute. WEIRD!!!
I fixed the problem adding:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {
    .style2 a {color: white;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **max-width** in the @media definition is wrong!

// line 695 on:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    /* Style adjustments for viewports 480px and over go here */
    header {
        height: 90px;
        background: #A3CE4B url('i/header_bg.jpg') top right no-repeat;
    }
    .page_width_1 {width: 1040px;}
    .ribbon_left {height: 164px;}
    .ribbon_right {height: 164px;}
    .style2 {color: white;}
    .style2 p {color: white;}
    input {width: 197px;}
    .date p {margin: 5px 35px 0 0;}
}
```

Comment: :-P Thank you. I fixed that but the text is still showing green.

Comment: i dont have an iphone to test this with - but I edited the file live in Chrome debugging, I also set the .style2 P color to RED just to highlight...then shrunk the browser window, text turns red. Both browsers are web kit based so I would expect this to fix it for you...Do you know how to force a refresh in iPhone Safari, your CSS files seem to be CACHED

Comment: Thank for helping. I clean the cache in the iPhone, in my pc and the in CMS. I made the following changes in the css: .stlyle2 p {color:pink;} For iPhone only .style2 p {color: red;} On the desktop the numbers are now pink (what ever the window size is). In the iPhone the numbers are still green, didn't change to red...

Comment: media only screen and (**max-width**: 480px)  NOT _max-device-width_

Comment: max-device-width will target iphones correctly, but if you use max-width, you can develop for the phone with your desktop browser.

Comment: Shouldn't the screen width value be 640px? where has 480 come from?

Comment: I agree. With max-width the css changes don't take effect in the iPhone. It has to be max-device-width. Just to let everyone know, with max-width the text changes between pink and red depending on the window size (in a Desktop) The iPhone, as I said, ignored that css.

Comment: iPhone 3( and less ) : 480 × 320 , iPhone4+ 960 × 640 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the color declaration from `default.css:144`:

```
p {font-size: 1.4em; color: #736E74;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that's not it. That css makes the text within p tags grey. I overrode that with '.style2 p {color: white;} but for some reason both of them are overridden in the iPhone for the color #4EB749 (I think).

Comment: That would be a little strange, since you've only used #4EB749 for some gradients/backgrounds.

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure about the green hex... Sorry but I'm don't know how to grab the hex color in the iphone, nor taking a screen shot...

Comment: It looks as though the color is #029547, though I can't see why it's inheriting it on iPhone. Try adding !important to your color:white rule and see if anything changes.

Comment: Also, press the home button and the lock button at the same time to take a screenshot.

Comment: I took an screen shot. Also I added important to the css and refreshed the cache. Still showing green in the iphone. This is unbelievable!